# Music Bot Discord (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

python show me this error:
raceback (most recent call last):
File , line 10, in 
import pynacl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynacl'

i use python 3.10.2

i installed pynacl.

Can you help me please?

Comment: try doing fresh install of it not much else to say honestly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install PyNaCl`

If you install **PyNaCl**, and this problem repeated

Try `pip freeze` and find `PyNaCl==1.4.0` (or other version)

You can solve this problem only this way

Comment: i find PyNacl with the command pip freeze but what i do later?